# Has anyone been able to create an image and publish through SSJS yet?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I've created a server-side JavaScript activity to create an image and run in automation, which is throwing an error, but the script working well in landing page:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: principal can not be
>   nullSystem.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter
>   name: principal can not be null    at
>   ExactTarget.Core.StackSettingCollection..ctor(IAccountContext
>   principal, String category, CacheType cacheType)    at
>   ExactTarget.ContentManagement.Instrumentation.Instruments.StatsDInstrument.<.ctor>b__1()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>   at
>   ExactTarget.ContentManagement.Instrumentation.Instruments.StatsDInstrument.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__8(Int64
>   elapsedMilliseconds)    at
>   ExactTarget.ContentManagement.Services.Assets.AssetService.Insert(IAssetV2
>   item)    at
>   PartnerAPIImplementation.ContentManagement.AssetImpl.CreateSingle(CreateOptions
>   options, APIObject apiObject)

Here's the sample code

```
<script runat="server">
    try {
        Platform.Load("Core","1");

        var testingDE1 = DataExtension.Init("My Demo DE");
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:349,Field2:'job starting'});


        var asset = Platform.Function.CreateObject("Asset");
        var nameIdReference = Platform.Function.CreateObject("NameIdReference");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(nameIdReference, "Id", 199); //html block type
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(asset, "AssetType", nameIdReference);
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:350,Field2:'job processing'});
        var txt = "<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center'><img src='https://www.cathaypacific.com/content/dam/focal-point/digital-library/destinations/dublin-dub/dublin-dub-offer.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.rendition.900.600.jpg' height='600' width='900' style='display: block; padding: 0px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;'></td></tr></table>";
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(asset, "Name", "0033");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(asset, "Content", txt);
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(asset, "ContentType", "imageblock");
        var statusAndRequest = [0,0];
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:234,Field2:'Hello World!!!!'});
        var response = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(asset, statusAndRequest, null);
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:351,Field2:'job ending'});
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:352,Field2:response});
        var status = statusAndRequest[0];
        var requestID = statusAndRequest[1];
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:353,Field2:status});
        testingDE1.Rows.Add({Field1:354,Field2:requestID});

    } catch (err) {
        var testingDE = DataExtension.Init("My Demo DE");
        testingDE.Rows.Add({Field1:123,Field2:Stringify(err)});
        testingDE.Rows.Add({Field1:234,Field2:'Hello World!!!!'});
        //Write(Stringify(err) + "</br>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: anybody have an idea for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with creating a code snippet. I solved my problem in using the REST API

```
var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = '{"clientId":"' + clientId + '",';
payload += '"clientSecret":"' + clientSecret + '"}';

var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).accessToken;

url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets";
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

payload = "{";
payload += ' "category": {';
payload += '  "id": 1234,';
payload += '  "name": "code snippets"';
payload += " },";
payload += ' "assetType": {';
payload += '  "id": 220,';
payload += '  "name": "codesnippetblock"';
payload += " },";
payload += ' "content": "code-snippet code",';
payload += ' "description": "description for code-snippet",';
payload += ' "name": "name of code-snippet"';
payload += "}";

var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
var statusCode = result["StatusCode"];
var response = result["Response"][0];
```

[Code snippet creation in Automation Studio script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226127/code-snippet-creation-in-automation-studio-script)